# Unique word array

Tags: java, arrays, split

So, I have a sentence with which I have used the split function to turn into an array of words.
Now (this is where I need help) I want to loop through this array and add each individual, unique word from the sentence to a second array, which is proving difficult for me as a beginner. Any solution or hint to get me on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

(I am aware that this question may seem rather stupid, but I reiterate, I am a beginner, so go easy on me)

Thanks :)

Comment: If you have the sentence I love love apple apple. You want to have the words i love apple in the second array ?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad, and looks like a "can you do my homework for me" question.  You should specify which part of the problem you're having an issue with, and then we can discuss.

Answer (score 1):

Im on my phone so i cant provide code example, but i can send you in the right direction.

You are gonne have a first loop (lets call it loopA) that is gonna iterate through you array that contains the words of the original sentence. For each element  in that array you are gonna have an "if" that checks if the current word in the array is present in the second one. If yes, jump over and continu to loop, if not, add the word to the second array ( array2[i] = array1[i]). To see if the array2 contains the current word,you can use a second loop to verify this. Good luck with the rest :)

Comment: LINQ expression? This is Java.

Comment: Oops haha used to answer c# questions x) dont mind this part then

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to maintain order, your duty is pretty simple:

```
String[] uniqueWords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(allWords)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

If you need to maintain order, you would do something like:

```
ArrayList<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>(allWords.length);
Set<String> track = new HashSet<>();
for (String word : allWords) {
    if (!track.contains(word)) {
        uniqueWords.add(word);
        track.add(word);
    }
}
return uniqueWords.toArray();
```

There are other not-so-simple, lightly-better-performant ways to do your thing, such as keep words in a trie, etc.

Comment: Your first line throws a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: You can use a `LinkedHashSet` to keep insertion order.

Comment: Slightly cleaner approach (assuming you're keeping a separate tracking set): `if (track.add(word)) uniqueWords.add(word);`

Comment: I like the contains then add because it clearly shows intent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat one liner that does what you want, where `words` is the initial array:

```
String[] uniqueWords = Arrays.stream(words).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```

You can also make a simple function to do this. Something like:

```
static String[] getUniqueWords(String[] words) {
    ArrayList<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        if (!uniqueWords.contains(word)) {
            uniqueWords.add(word);
        }
    }

    return uniqueWords.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` rather than `Set`?

Comment: Or `new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(words)).toArray(new String[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a HashSet like this

```
Set mySet = new HashSet();
for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    mySet.add(array[i]);
```

Then, you should use an iterator to create the second array

```
Iterator iterator = mySet.iterator();
String newArray = new String[array.length];
int counter=0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     newArray[counter] = iterator.next();
     counter++; 
}
```

Comment: What is this, Java 4?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array. Use a `Set` instead. This will ensure that only the unique words get used without you needing to worry about the logic.

```
String original = "This sentence has has some duplicate words words on purpose and it has some extra words as well";
String[] words = original.toLowerCase().split(" ");
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
uniqueWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));

for (String word : uniqueWords) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Since this will add the same word twice if they have different cases you can use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` to make them all have the same case.

Additionally, punctuation can make it look like a different word (ex. a period at the end of a sentence) so be sure to remove any punctuation when splitting the `String` into an array.

Comment: Who said anything about case?

Comment: @shmosel Generally when people refer to 'unique' words they mean how its spelled, not what case it is in. I felt it important to point it out in case the OP didn't think of it.